# PIC 18F4431 PWM Problem

Tags: pic, pwm

I'm attempting get a very basic PWM code to work.  However all PWM outputs seem stuck on +5V with no proper PWM output.  It works perfectly in the simulator but not on the chip.  Any ideas welcome?

```
    include <P18f4431.INC>

CONFIG     OSC = IRC
CONFIG     FCMEN = OFF
CONFIG     IESO = OFF
CONFIG     PWRTEN = OFF
CONFIG     BOREN = ON
CONFIG     BORV = 20
CONFIG     WDTEN = OFF
CONFIG     WDPS = 1
CONFIG     WINEN = OFF
CONFIG     PWMPIN = OFF
CONFIG     LPOL = LOW
CONFIG     HPOL = LOW
CONFIG     T1OSCMX = OFF
CONFIG     FLTAMX = RC1
CONFIG     SSPMX = RD1
CONFIG     PWM4MX = RB5
CONFIG     EXCLKMX = RC3
CONFIG     MCLRE = ON
CONFIG     CP0 = OFF
CONFIG     CP1 = OFF
CONFIG     CP2 = OFF
CONFIG     CP3 = OFF
CONFIG     CPD = OFF
CONFIG     WRT1 = OFF
CONFIG     WRT2 = OFF
CONFIG     WRT3 = OFF
CONFIG     WRTC = OFF
CONFIG     WRTB = OFF
CONFIG     WRTD = OFF
CONFIG     EBTR0 = OFF
CONFIG     EBTR1 = OFF
CONFIG     EBTR2 = OFF
CONFIG     EBTR3 = OFF
CONFIG     EBTRB = OFF
CONFIG     STVREN = OFF
CONFIG     DEBUG = OFF
CONFIG     CPB = OFF
CONFIG     WRT0 = OFF
CONFIG     LVP = OFF


;***********VARIABLE DEFINITIONS******************

Timer   res 1
Timer2  res 1


;*******************************************************************************
; Reset Vector
;*******************************************************************************

STARTUP  CODE    0x00           ; processor reset vector
  GOTO    START                   ; go to beginning of program


 ;*******************************************************************************
 ; MAIN PROGRAM
 ;******************************************************************************

 PROG1 code

START:

;; Initialise PORTB
;  CLRF  PORTB
;  CLRF LATB
;  movlw 0x00
;  movwf TRISB
;movlw 0xff
;movwf PORTB

movlw    b'10111110'
movwf    TRISC
;  bsf  PORTC, 0

movlw    b'11010000'
movwf    TRISD
bcf  PORTD, 0

 ;***********SET UP OSCILLATOR**************

bsf   OSCCON, IRCF0
bsf   OSCCON, IRCF1
bsf   OSCCON, IRCF2

call INIT_PCPWM


;***********MAIN ROUTINE **********************************

;turn on lamp to show power
bsf PORTD, 1

movlw   d'88'
movwf   PDC0L  ;'set the PWM duty cycle
movlw   d'00'
movwf   PDC0H
bcf INTCON, RBIF
bcf INTCON, RBPU

Loop:
  call Delay
  GOTO Loop                         ; loop forever

 ;*********DELAY ROUTINES**********************

Delay

movlw   d'5'
movwf   Timer
movwf   Timer2

Loop2:
  nop
Loop1:
nop
decfsz Timer, f
goto Loop1
decfsz Timer2, f
goto Loop2

return

;***********************************************
 ;***********SET UP PWM***********************

INIT_PCPWM

movlw   b'01000000' ; deadtime
movwf   DTCON

movlw   b'00000000'
movwf   PTCON0  ; Postcale 1:1, PWM time base input is Fosc/4
                ; PWM time base mode is free-running for edge-aligned operation
movlw   b'10000000'
movwf   PTCON1  ; Count up, timer on

movlw   d'99'    ;PTPERL and PTPERH are set up for a XX PWM frequency
movwf   PTPERL
movlw   d'00'
movwf   PTPERH

movlw   b'01000000' ;configure PWMCON0
movwf   PWMCON0     ; enable PWM 0 to 5, all PWM I/O pairs set to complimentary

movlw   b'00000000' ;configure PWMCON0
movwf   PWMCON1     ; Special event postscaler set to 1
                ; Special event trigger occurs when time-base is counting upward
                ; Updates from duty cycle and period buffer registers are enabled
                ; Ouput overides via OVDCON are synchronous to the PWM timebase

movlw   b'11111111' ; no output override
movwf   OVDCOND

movlw   b'00000000' ;OVDCONS is configured such that all PWM outputs are 0 on power up
movwf   OVDCONS

movlw   b'10010001' ;FAULT A and B enabled in catastrophic mode
movwf   FLTCONFIG

movlw   0x00    ;SECTCMPL and SEVTCMPH are cleared
movwf   SEVTCMPL
movlw   0x00
movwf   SEVTCMPH

bcf FLTCONFIG, FLTAEN   ; disable fault condition
bcf FLTCONFIG, FLTBEN   ; disable fault condition

bsf PTCON1, PTEN    ; enable the PWM time base

return

;***********************************************
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure but it might have something to do with your ptper value.  for example when i calculate your resolution which is ln(Fosc/Fpwm)/ln2 i get 8.64 bits.  I believe you want this to be an integer, such as 8 or 10 bits.  So if you backsolve to get the correct pwm frequency, you can then get a proper ptper value.  once again, not sure if this is the issue, but it might be..

Comment: I've changed PTPER to 255 to give an 8 bit resolution but still no joy I'm afraid.

Comment: I have found that the FLTCONFIG register was set up incorrectly and a fault had been enabled.
All working fine now, thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Probably harmless, but this doesn't look right:

```
bcf INTCON, RBPU
```

I think it should be:

```
bsf INTCON2, RBPU
```

...or let it default to 1 to disable weak pull ups on PORTB (PWM0/1/2/3/5/4). As it is coded, it may just be turning off the GIE bit (disabling General Interrupts).

The only other thing I see is that you enable the PWM time base (PTEN) by:

```
movlw   b'10000000'
movwf   PTCON1  ; Count up, timer on
```

...and then later enable it again with:

```
bsf PTCON1, PTEN    ; enable the PWM time base
```

I would have disabled it while setting things up and then enabled it afterwards. But after reading the data sheet I can't see why that would make a difference anyway.

Comment: Thanks I just tried these suggestions but they don't seem to help.  Although I will implement them as best practice.  Interestingly all ports are high so they are not acting in complementary mode.  Also if I change the polarity of the configuration bit all ports go low.  Some possible clues perhaps?

Comment: It might be a good idea to post a circuit diagram. Have you tied MCLR to +5V (via a 10-40k resistor)?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation points to post an image but I am basically driving it using a Pickit 2 device with MCLR tied to 5V via a 10k resistor.  I'm using the internal oscillator so I might try using an external one to see if that will make a difference.  Although the clock seems to be working as I can get the USART working successfully.